# Blanks showing up in SSRS email subscription for items filtered out - Help needed

Tags: reporting-services, pdf-generation, ssrs-subscription

I have recently adjusted an existing ssrs report to filter out clients that don't hit a certain criteria.  When I look at the report on ssrs platform, it looks perfect.  but once I send out a PDF from a subscription, the PDF now displays blank spaces where the filtered out clients would be.

For example, the original report would have 55 pages of clients.  Then the new report that filters out the clients will only have 10 pages.  and I can see that this worked scrolling through the report on ssrs.  as soon as I open up the PDF from the subscription... I now have 55 pages again but they are mostly blank due to the clients being filtered out.

Has anyone dealt with this issue before and if so, can anyone help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you filtering at the row group in the tablix or in the dataset? If you filter at the row group, the space will remain.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The filter is being applied from the query bringing in the data.  I should also mention that I am doing this to pre existing report and I added two text boxes to the view.  I am reading that changing the view can cause issues like this as well but that doesn't seem to be the case here.